# MySQL JOIN query with 3 tables

Tags: mysql, join

I have 3 tables:
projects, users, users_projects
I need query that takes
projects.id
where projects.id = users_projects.project_id
where users.id = users_projects.user_id
i tried something like this:

```
SELECT p.id FROM projects AS p, users_projects AS up, users AS u 
WHERE p.id = up.project_id AND u.id = up.user_id
```

and

```
SELECT p.id FROM projects AS p 
INNER JOIN users_projects AS up ON p.id = up.project_id
INNER JOIN users AS u ON u.id = up.user_id
```

this didn't worked for me, maybe someone help me?

Comment: any attempts so far?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking - can you provide some sample data and the result you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Please take time and read about SQL joins [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Comment: please add your try code

Comment: @sgk Please don't post link to w3school

Comment: Ah, fall - when institutions of higher learning fling open their doors to welcome a new crop of students who, eager to expand their horizons, post their homework on StackOverflow and then slope off to the nearest pub, confident that their assignments will soon be completed without them having to expend actual effort. They'll be gone by mid-winter, sent back to hearth and home by professorial admonition in the form of failing grades (for if someone else does the assignment, what does the student learn?) but it's nice to see that the circle still turns and time marches on. Best of luck.

Comment: @JohnGuan: May I ask why? I thought it is a good place for the OP to learn about joins?

Comment: @sgk Because W3Schools is harming the community with inaccurate information.

Comment: @JohnGuan for what the OP is asking, it seems they could do well reading up. W3Schools is a good starting point. As for the question, however, **MrCoder** 's answer is pretty good - not too much handed on a plate, but answers/points the OP in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Please could you look over the **Inner Join** in the picture below. From that, you can create an inner join on two tables. By reading/understanding this, you should be able to create a join on both a third and forth table (as many as you want actually, the logic is the same).

Pretty much, understand the inner join and you can use this for all! :)

[image: Basic SQL Joins]